# Google Contacts read only (OAuth 2.0)

Tags: oauth, gmail, contacts

We're using OAuth 2.0 to access Gmail Contacts. Do you know if it is possible to request access (scope) in such a way that the authorization pop-up indicates that we need read only access.

Right now the pop say says  "Manage your contacts" - view and manage your Google Contacts.
This "manage" part is discouraging to many users while all we need is to view them.

So far we tried the following scopes but the pop-up is the same ("Manage contacts"):
- https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/
- https://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people

Thanks,
Piotr

Comment: So weird, google should not grant write access in OAUTH

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is, just use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly` as the scope and it will say "View your contacts".

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow, that worked.  However, I'm not sure how anyone was supposed to know this.  The api documentation at the oatuh2playground (https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/) did not list that scope, and " https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ " doesn't convey any relation to contacts at all.  +1 to you sir for the help on navigating this treachery.

Comment: I downvoted this because even thought the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly results in "View your contacts" in the authorization prompt - the token received from google is completely useless with this permission and calling google.com/m8/feeds with that token fails misarabely

Comment: Would just like to comment on behalf of Google: the scope mentioned in this answer will not work as intended, and does not offer read-only access to the Contacts API v3.

Comment: @VicFryzel Any update from Google on this?  Can we request read-only access to contacts?  Our users are discouranged from the "manage" permission and we only need read-access.

Comment: Our site is running into this issue as well. Any update on this?

Comment: I just tried calling the m8/feeds with this scope and worked well

Answer (score 4):

For contacts, the lowest granularity of scope that google has is read/write. Read only access is not available.