# Is there any documentation for read-only access to the Google Contacts API?

Tags: gmail, google-api, contacts

I want to get read-only access to a user's Google Contacts.

There was another Stackoverflow member that wanted to do this, and received the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741382/1334875):

> Yes, there is, just use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly as the scope and it will say "View your contacts".

This exchange is the only reference to this read-only access to Google Contacts I can find using Google.

Simply using the access token obtained from this to attempt to read from the usual Google Contacts API (i.e. `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds`) fails with insufficient permissions.

Similarly, simply using the Google Contacts API on this new target fails with 404 errors (for example `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly/default/full`).

Is there any documentation anywhere on how to actually use this API, or is the only permissible way to access the Google Contacts API with full read-write access?

Comment: I'm also interested in this question, to fully use "readonly", did you find a solution? I also asked this on this blogpost: https://mydnic.be/post/how-to-get-all-gmail-contacts-with-laravel-5