# google contacts api make contact readonly

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api

I am using Google Contacts API v3 to create and update contacts and groups in Google accounts.

Is there any way to set these contacts and groups to be read only? So that they can't be changed from the side of Google account, but only in my system?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, not supported. See [Google Contacts read only (OAuth 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531066/google-contacts-read-only-oauth-2-0)

There is some "readonly" scope that doesn't actually work with the v3 API and calling google.com/m8/feeds will fail to get contacts.

My suggestion is to up-vote this issue: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4788 in attempt to get Google to add it. But I wouldn't hold my breath on it happening soon unfortunately.

EDIT: Update! It is now supported by Google in their v3 API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ via 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly' instead of 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds' (RW access)